# Connect to AWS MQTT broker using openssl intermediate certificate

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, esp8266, aws-iot, arduino-esp8266

I have some problem with this project https://github.com/debsahu/ESP-MQTT-AWS-IoT-Core: if I use the AWS certificates everything works good, but if I use certificates created with openssl, the code return this error: "failed, reason -> Connection Accepted < try again in 5 seconds"

To create the intermediate certificate (best practise for aws) i used this guide: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html

```
#ifdef ESP32
#include <WiFi.h>
#elif defined(ESP8266)
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#else
#error Platform not supported
#endif
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h> //https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson (use v6.xx)
#include <time.h>
#define emptyString String()

//Follow instructions from https://github.com/debsahu/ESP-MQTT-AWS-IoT-        Core/blob/master/doc/README.md
//Enter values in secrets.h ▼
#include "secrets.h"

#ifndef PIO_PLATFORM
//#define USE_PUB_SUB  //uncomment to use PubSubClient(https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient)
#endif

#if !(ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_MAJOR == 6 and ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_MINOR >= 7)
#error "Install ArduinoJson v6.7.0-beta or higher"
#endif

const int MQTT_PORT = 8883;
const char MQTT_SUB_TOPIC[] = "$aws/things/OggettoZero/shadow/update";
const char MQTT_PUB_TOPIC[] = "$aws/things/OggettoZero/shadow/update";

#ifdef USE_SUMMER_TIME_DST
uint8_t DST = 1;
#else
uint8_t DST = 0;
#endif

WiFiClientSecure net;

#ifdef ESP8266
BearSSL::X509List cert(cacert);
BearSSL::X509List client_crt(client_cert);
BearSSL::PrivateKey key(privkey);
#endif

#ifdef USE_PUB_SUB
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#if defined(USE_PUB_SUB) and defined(PIO_PLATFORM) // PIO has issues, needs MQTT.h definition or else freaks out
#include <MQTT.h>
#endif
PubSubClient client(net);
#else
#include <MQTT.h>
MQTTClient client;
#endif

unsigned long lastMillis = 0;
time_t now;
time_t nowish = 1510592825;

void NTPConnect(void)
{
  Serial.print("Setting time using SNTP");
  configTime(TIME_ZONE * 3600, DST * 3600, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
  now = time(nullptr);
  while (now < nowish)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    now = time(nullptr);
  }
  Serial.println("done!");
  struct tm timeinfo;
  gmtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
  Serial.print("Current time: ");
  Serial.print(asctime(&timeinfo));
}

#ifdef USE_PUB_SUB

void messageReceivedPubSub(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
  Serial.print("Received [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("]: ");
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void pubSubErr(int8_t MQTTErr)
{
  if (MQTTErr == MQTT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
    Serial.print("Connection tiemout");
  else if (MQTTErr == MQTT_CONNECTION_LOST)
    Serial.print("Connection lost");
  else if (MQTTErr == MQTT_CONNECT_FAILED)
    Serial.print("Connect failed");
  else if (MQTTErr == MQTT_DISCONNECTED)
    Serial.print("Disconnected");
  else if (MQTTErr == MQTT_CONNECTED)
    Serial.print("Connected");
  else if (MQTTErr == MQTT_CONNECT_BAD_PROTOCOL)
    Serial.print("Connect bad protocol");
  else if (MQTTErr == MQTT_CONNECT_BAD_CLIENT_ID)
    Serial.print("Connect bad Client-ID");
  else if (MQTTErr == MQTT_CONNECT_UNAVAILABLE)
    Serial.print("Connect unavailable");
  else if (MQTTErr == MQTT_CONNECT_BAD_CREDENTIALS)
    Serial.print("Connect bad credentials");
  else if (MQTTErr == MQTT_CONNECT_UNAUTHORIZED)
    Serial.print("Connect unauthorized");
}

#else

void messageReceived(String &topic, String &payload)
{
  Serial.println("Recieved [" + topic + "]: " + payload);
}

void lwMQTTErr(lwmqtt_err_t reason)
{
  if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_SUCCESS)
    Serial.print("Success");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_BUFFER_TOO_SHORT)
    Serial.print("Buffer too short");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_VARNUM_OVERFLOW)
    Serial.print("Varnum overflow");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_NETWORK_FAILED_CONNECT)
    Serial.print("Network failed connect");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT)
    Serial.print("Network timeout");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_NETWORK_FAILED_READ)
    Serial.print("Network failed read");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_NETWORK_FAILED_WRITE)
    Serial.print("Network failed write");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_REMAINING_LENGTH_OVERFLOW)
    Serial.print("Remaining length overflow");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_REMAINING_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
    Serial.print("Remaining length mismatch");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_MISSING_OR_WRONG_PACKET)
    Serial.print("Missing or wrong packet");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_CONNECTION_DENIED)
    Serial.print("Connection denied");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_FAILED_SUBSCRIPTION)
    Serial.print("Failed subscription");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_SUBACK_ARRAY_OVERFLOW)
    Serial.print("Suback array overflow");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_err_t::LWMQTT_PONG_TIMEOUT)
    Serial.print("Pong timeout");
}

void lwMQTTErrConnection(lwmqtt_return_code_t reason)
{
  if (reason == lwmqtt_return_code_t::LWMQTT_CONNECTION_ACCEPTED)
    Serial.print("Connection Accepted");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_return_code_t::LWMQTT_UNACCEPTABLE_PROTOCOL)
    Serial.print("Unacceptable Protocol");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_return_code_t::LWMQTT_IDENTIFIER_REJECTED)
    Serial.print("Identifier Rejected");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_return_code_t::LWMQTT_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE)
    Serial.print("Server Unavailable");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_return_code_t::LWMQTT_BAD_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD)
    Serial.print("Bad UserName/Password");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_return_code_t::LWMQTT_NOT_AUTHORIZED)
    Serial.print("Not Authorized");
  else if (reason == lwmqtt_return_code_t::LWMQTT_UNKNOWN_RETURN_CODE)
    Serial.print("Unknown Return Code");
}
#endif

void connectToMqtt(bool nonBlocking = false)
{
  Serial.print("MQTT connecting ");
  while (!client.connected())
  {
    if (client.connect(THINGNAME))
    {
      Serial.println("connected!");
      if (!client.subscribe(MQTT_SUB_TOPIC))
#ifdef USE_PUB_SUB
        pubSubErr(client.state());
#else
        lwMQTTErr(client.lastError());
#endif
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print("failed, reason -> ");
#ifdef USE_PUB_SUB
      pubSubErr(client.state());
#else
      lwMQTTErrConnection(client.returnCode());
#endif
      if (!nonBlocking)
      {
        Serial.println(" < try again in 5 seconds");
        delay(5000);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println(" <");
      }
    }
    if (nonBlocking)
      break;
  }
}

void connectToWiFi(String init_str)
{
  if (init_str != emptyString)
    Serial.print(init_str);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  if (init_str != emptyString)
    Serial.println("ok!");
}

void checkWiFiThenMQTT(void)
{
  connectToWiFi("Checking WiFi");
  connectToMqtt();
}

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 5000;

void checkWiFiThenMQTTNonBlocking(void)
{
  connectToWiFi(emptyString);
  if (millis() - previousMillis >= interval && !client.connected()) {
    previousMillis = millis();
    connectToMqtt(true);
  }
}

void checkWiFiThenReboot(void)
{
  connectToWiFi("Checking WiFi");
  Serial.print("Rebooting");
  ESP.restart();
}

void sendData(void)
{
  DynamicJsonDocument jsonBuffer(JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3) + 100);
  JsonObject root = jsonBuffer.to<JsonObject>();
  JsonObject state = root.createNestedObject("state");
  JsonObject state_reported = state.createNestedObject("reported");
  state_reported["value"] = random(100);
  Serial.printf("Sending  [%s]: ", MQTT_PUB_TOPIC);
  serializeJson(root, Serial);
  Serial.println();
  char shadow[measureJson(root) + 1];
  serializeJson(root, shadow, sizeof(shadow));
#ifdef USE_PUB_SUB
  if (!client.publish(MQTT_PUB_TOPIC, shadow, false))
    pubSubErr(client.state());
#else
  if (!client.publish(MQTT_PUB_TOPIC, shadow, false, 0))
    lwMQTTErr(client.lastError());
#endif
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
#ifdef ESP32
  WiFi.setHostname(THINGNAME);
#else
  WiFi.hostname(THINGNAME);
#endif
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  connectToWiFi(String("Attempting to connect to SSID: ") + String(ssid));

  NTPConnect();

#ifdef ESP32
  net.setCACert(cacert);
  net.setCertificate(client_cert);
  net.setPrivateKey(privkey);
#else
  net.setTrustAnchors(&cert);
  net.setClientRSACert(&client_crt, &key);
#endif

#ifdef USE_PUB_SUB
  client.setServer(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT);
  client.setCallback(messageReceivedPubSub);
#else
  client.begin(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, net);
  client.onMessage(messageReceived);
#endif
  connectToMqtt();
}

void loop()
{
  now = time(nullptr);
  if (!client.connected())
  {
    checkWiFiThenMQTT();
    //checkWiFiThenMQTTNonBlocking();
    //checkWiFiThenReboot();
  }
  else
  {
    client.loop();
    if (millis() - lastMillis > 5000)
    {
      lastMillis = millis();
      sendData();
    }
  }
}
```

In file secret.h I put the certificates created with openssl: private  key, device certificate and CA certificate.

I expected that the connection will work exactly like with the AWS certificates, but the code return me this error: "failed, reason -> Connection Accepted < try again in 5 seconds" and I don't what kind of error it can be!

Answer (score 1):

When using your own generated keys, you need to create and register the corresponding CA certificate with AWS IoT. This and additional necessary steps are described here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-certs-your-own.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I forgot to say that I have already registered my CA certificate in AWS Iot. I followed all the steps described in aws doc.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem!

After following this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/building-an-aws-iot-core-device-using-aws-serverless-and-an-esp32/
I downloaded the certs, added them to the secrets.h, flashed the ESP32 and got `LWMQTT_NETWORK_FAILED_READ`.

Two steps solved my Problem:

- Had to create a Policy - like here: https://github.com/debsahu/ESP-MQTT-AWS-IoT-Core/blob/master/doc/README.md#create-a-policy
- Now in AWS IoT you have to connect you Policy with your certificate